# Sharing only text android studio

Tags: android, string, textview

I'm developing a test app (for learning) that gets the user location and then puts the location values in a string to be shared via email, etc...

The location code is working very well, but when the email interface is called, there is a lot of code coming together with, like this:

> "Android.widget.TextView{f05b211V.ED.... ......ID 48,108-1032, 165 #7f0d0053 applied/tv_coordinate}"

How can I solve this and get only the correct values (latitude and longitude, in the case) shown?

Thank you all!

My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private TextView tvCoordinate;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvCoordinate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_coordinate);

    callConnection();
}


private synchronized void callConnection() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


}

String msg4; 



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);



    Log.i("LOG", "onConnected(" + bundle + ")");

    Location l = LocationServices
            .FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (l != null) {
        Log.i("LOG", "latitude: " + l.getLatitude());
        Log.i("LOG", "longitude: " + l.getLongitude());
        tvCoordinate.setText(l.getLatitude() + " | " + l.getLongitude());

        msg4 = String.format("%s", tvCoordinate);
        resultado.setText(msg4);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("LOG", "onConnectionSuspended(" + i + ")");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("LOG", "onConnectionFailed(" + connectionResult + ")");
}



public void enviardados(View view) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = String.format("A localizacao e %s", msg4);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Localizacao");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Compartilhar via"));
}
```

}

Comment: *there is a lot of code coming together with* I am unable to understand. Pls elaborate.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the string from textview and not its object

```
        msg4 = String.format("%s", tvCoordinate.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`msg4 = String.format("%s", tvCoordinate);`

do you try to put the text on tvCoordinate to msg4 on the code above ?

if yes, try to change that code to :

`msg4 = tvCoordinate.getText().toString();`